# Prove that the sum of series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{(2k+2)!!}$ is equal to $\log 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Prove that the sum of series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{(2k+2)!!}$ is equal to $\log 2$-

I tried to change the double factorial to single but I failed to do this.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7):

If $n$ is even then $n!!=2^{n/2}\cdot (n/2)!$. Hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{(2k+2)!!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1/2)^k}{k}=-\log(1-1/2)=\log(2).$$

Comment: ... since $(2(k+1))!!=2^{k+1} (k+1)!$.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is observing that $$S=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(k-1\right)!}{\left(2k\right)!!}=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\left(2k\right)!!}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k-1}e^{-x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{\left(2k\right)!!}e^{-x}dx
 $$  but the power series inside the integral has a well known closed form $$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{x^{k}}{\left(2k\right)!!}=e^{x/2}
 $$ so $$S=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\left(e^{x/2}-1\right)e^{-x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x/2}-e^{-x}}{x}dx
 $$ and now we can use the [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) and get $$S=\color{red}{\log\left(2\right)}$$ as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\pars{2k + 2}!! =
> \pars{2k + 2}\pars{2k}\pars{2k - 2}\ldots 2 = 2^{k + 1}\pars{k + 1}k
> \pars{k - 1}\ldots 1 =
> 2^{k + 1}\pars{k + 1}!}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k! \over \pars{2k + 2}!!}} & = 
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{k + 1}\pars{k + 1}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{k + 1}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}\,\dd x =
\half\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{x \over 2}^{k}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\half\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over 1 - x/2} = \color{#f00}{\ln\pars{2}}
\end{align}